# Any image captioning networks available yet?

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision

Looking for an image captioning network to run in a notebook. I didn't see any on the [NN Repo](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository). Has anyone imported one successfully?

Comment: The Applications section of the doc for ImageCases shows how you can use ImageCases to caption images. To help people respond to your question, can you say what capability you're looking for? And whether the built-in function ImageCases is not sufficient?

Comment: ImageCases does not really give a caption, just a bag of objects, I'm looking for something more like a descriptive sentence from an image-to-text model like Clip or Blip2.